# How to map "make" to "make | copen"?

Tags: key-bindings

It would be fine if after `:make` command vim opened the new buffer with errors and put the cursor to it. Exactly like `:make | copen` command. How to map sequence `:make | copen`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create an abbreviation in the command line mode by adding this to your vimrc:

```
cabbrev mc make<bar>copen
```

Now when you'll type `mc` in the command line it will be replaced by `make|copen` making it faster to type.

You could also create a mapping to invoke the commands you want:

```
nnoremap <key> :make<bar>copen<CR>
```

---

**EDIT** As @Sato Katsura pointed it out in the comment my first version of `cabbrev` is not a good one: Indeed in the first version `mc` will be replaced no matter where it is placed in the command line, so for example I you want to search in a buffer for the string `mc` and you try to hit `/mc` it will be replaced by `/make|copen`.

To resolve that @Sato linked [an interesting tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev). With the following syntax `mc` will be replaced only if it is the first thing typed in the command line:

```
cabbrev make <c-r>=(getcmdtype()==':' && getcmdpos()==1 ? 'make<bar>copen' : 'make')<CR>
```

Comment: Thank you! Both spells work well. I put `cabbrev make make<bar>copen` in .vimrc (I more used to type `make') it works.

Comment: Here we go again: `cabbrev` is [not that simple](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev).

Answer (score 7):

The best solution is to not create a mapping at all.

Simply put the following snippet in your `vimrc`:

```
augroup quickfix
    autocmd!
    " automatic location/quickfix window
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost [^l]* cwindow
    autocmd QuickFixCmdPost    l* lwindow
augroup END
```

This will open the quickfix window automatically after `:make` and other quickfix-related commands like `:grep`, when there are valid errors (`:cwindow` versus `:copen`).

Same for location-related commands like `:lvimgrep`.

--- EDIT ---

The general structure of an autocommand is:

```
autocmd [<group>] <EventName>[,<EventName>[,...]] <pattern> <command>
```

Here, `<pattern>` is matched against Ex command names:

- `l*` matches all command names starting with `l` (`:lgrep`, `:lmake`, etc.),
- `[^l]*` matches all command names *not* starting with `l` (`:grep`, `:make`, etc.).

Quickfix-related command names start with different letters while location-related command names all start with an `l` so `l` as first character is a convenient way to discriminate them.

Comment: This solution doesn't put cursor to the quickfix window, but `make | copen` does.

Comment: Well, just add `| wincmd p` after `cwindow`.

Comment: `| wincmd p` spell doesn't works either. It puts cursor to the first error in the window with source code not to quickfix window.

Comment: could you explain, please, where do the patterns `[^l]*` and `l*` come from? I mean, what are they for? Or they aren't patterns?

Comment: @user907860, see my edit.